# Authenticate multiple application with Ruby CAS Server

Tags: ruby, rubycas-client, rubycas-server

I have two different web applications which are already build. Now one new requirement comes i.e Implement Common Authentication. My one application is build in rails and another application is build in Drupal. I have installed `ruby-casserver`, but for the CAS we need to set Authenticator in `config.yml` file, I have set that.

But my problem is how to migrate my old users on CAS, because I am storing the username and also password(i.e encrypetd) on CAS server. Encrypted Passwords which are stored in CAS user table are encrypted using SHA1 algorithm. But the oldest user which are on Drupal uses the MD5 for password encryption.

So my question is how to migrate old users on CAS, or how to Design the CAS which can authenticate for Rails and Drupal users.

Answer (score 0):

if you understand how your passwords are hashed, all you have to do is make sure that your authenticator hashes the passwords in the same way -- overriding it if you need to.  Take a look at [CASino](https://github.com/rbCAS/CASino), it is a CAS server that makes it pretty easy to override authenticators; also it allows multiple data sources to be used simultaneously, be it multiple databases or LDAP.